# RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw<Entity>(DbSet<Entity>, string, params object[])' requires a receiver of type 'DbSet<Entity>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am new to the .net core and Facing below issue while running the store procedure.

Error: RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw(DbSet, string, params object[])' requires a receiver of type 'DbSet
Please have a look below code,

```
[NotMapped]
public class Result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

 public class UserDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Email address required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Email Address")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
    [Index("IX_UserEmail", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [RegularExpression("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(.{8,15})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    [ForeignKey("LoginReference")]
    public int? LoginReferenceId { get; set; }
    public virtual LoginReference LoginReference { get; set; }
    public bool Suspend { get; set; } = true;
}

public interface IRegisterRepository
{
    Result RegisterUsers(Register register);
}



public class SQLRegisterRepository : IRegisterRepository
    {
        readonly DecentDesignersDbContext context;
        public Result RegisterUsers(Register register)
        {
            return context.UserDetails.FromSqlRaw<Result>("spRegiterUsers {0},{1}", register.UserMail, register.EncryptPassword)
                .ToList().FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include your DbContext in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw(DbSet, string, params
> object[])' requires a receiver of type 'DbSet Please have a look below
> code

This error indicates that you cannot automatically convert the result to the `Result` type while executing the `UserDetails` stored procedure.

Here is the official document explanation from [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-3.1).

If you want to display the results returned by the stored procedure in other types, you can use the `Select` method to return the corresponding type after obtaining the results, please refer to the following code：

```
public Result RegisterUsers(Register register)
{
    return context.UserDetails.FromSqlRaw("spRegiterUsers {0},{1}", register.UserMail, register.EncryptPassword)
        .ToList()  
        .Select(x => new Result()
        {
            Id = x.UserId ,
            Message = x.UserEmail //you can change to any field you want.
        }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer